# Create path and filename from string in Python

Tags: python

Given the following strings:

```
dir/dir2/dir3/dir3/file.txt
dir/dir2/dir3/file.txt
example/directory/path/file.txt
```

I am looking to create the correct directories and blank files within those directories.

I imported the `os` module and I saw that there is a `mkdir` function, but I am not sure what to do to create the whole path and blank files. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer on all your questions (directory creation and blank file creation)

```
import os

fileList = ["dir/dir2/dir3/dir3/file.txt",
    "dir/dir2/dir3/file.txt",
    "example/directory/path/file.txt"]

for file in fileList:
    dir = os.path.dirname(file)
    # create directory if it does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    # Create blank file if it does not exist
    with open(file, "w"):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, given that try to create directory under a directory that doesn't exist, `os.mkdir` will raise an error. As such, you need to walk through the paths and check whether each of the subdirectories has or has not been created (and use `mkdir` as required). Alternative, you can use `os.makedirs` to handle this iteration for you.

A full path can be split into directory name and filename with `os.path.split`.

Example:

```
import os
(dirname, filename) = os.path.split('dir/dir2/dir3/dir3/file.txt')
os.makedirs(dirname)
```

Given we have a set of dirs we want to create, simply use a for loop to iterate through them. Schematically:

```
dirlist = ['dir1...', 'dir2...', 'dir3...']
for dir in dirlist:
   os.makedirs( ... )
```

Comment: You can use [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create the entire path at once.